# Deleting then adding text to xml field

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm interested in changing an XML file to create an html file with a table.

Here a sample of the original XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <item>
    <title>Electronic Payments for State Taxes and Fees</title>
    <link>http://mesharpe.metapress.com/link.asp?id=T861142L5675QQW2</link>
    <dc:identifier>DOI 10.2753/PMR1530-9576360406</dc:identifier>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>The Determinants of Union Attitudes among Community College Professors</title>
    <link>http://baywood.metapress.com/link.asp?id=R216M2L6263165N1</link>
    <dc:identifier>DOI 10.2190/CN.32.4.a</dc:identifier>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Using Dedicated Nurses to Improve Core Measures Compliance</title>
    <link>http://rss.sciencedirect.com/...link>
    <dc:identifier>http://rss.sciencedirect.com/...</dc:identifier>
  </item>
</library>
```

I want to create something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:h="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"     xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/1.2/basic/"         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:mn="http://usefulinc.com/rss/manifest/"     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
  <body>
    <h1 align="center">Something</h1>
    <table border="1" width="700" align="center">
      <tr bgcolor="#CC661F">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Identifier</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Electronic Payments for State Taxes and Fees</td>
        <td>http://dx.doi.org/10.2753/PMR1530-9576360406</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>The Determinants of Union Attitudes among Community College Professors</td>
        <td>http://dx.doi.org/10.2190/CN.32.4.a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Using Dedicated Nurses to Improve Core Measures Compliance</td>
        <td>http://rss.sciencedirect.com/...</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

So for the field *dc:identifier* there is either a link or a DOI with a number following it.  For every one with a DOI I want to remove the DOI and the space and then add the http://dx.doi.org/ in front, therefore creating a link in the table.

Any hints on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Edit:  I've never worked with XSLT files before and I only have a barebones template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:h="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/1.2/basic/"     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:mn="http://usefulinc.com/rss/manifest/"     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1 align="center">Title</h1>
        <table border="1" width="700" align="center">
          <tr bgcolor="#CC661F">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Link</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="//h:item">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="h:title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="dc:identifier"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Have you already tried writing an [xslt template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSLT) and can you share that with us as well?

Comment: Use the substring function.

Comment: I put my xslt template up there.  I doubt that helps.  I'll look into the substring function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to work with `for-each`, you should take advantage of XSLT's template matching mechanism.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:h="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:prism="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/1.2/basic/"     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:mn="http://usefulinc.com/rss/manifest/"     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1 align="center">Title</h1>
        <table border="1" width="700" align="center">
          <tr bgcolor="#CC661F">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Link</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//h:item" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- create one row for each item -->
  <xsl:template match="h:item">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="h:title | dc:identifier" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- title and identifier become table columns -->
  <xsl:template match="h:title | dc:identifier">
    <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- text nodes that start DOI are massaged to add the appropriate prefix -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(., 'DOI ')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://dx.doi.org/', substring(., 5))" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The trick here is that the default template handling text nodes simply prints out the node's value, what I've done here is add an additional template just for text nodes that start "DOI " to add the `http://dx.doi.org/` prefix.

Comment: That worked beautifully!  Now I just have to figure out how you did that!  Thank you!